# hover in mobile safari

Tags: css, hover, mobile-safari

I try to add a hover effect to one button in css. I will build an app with mobile safari. I use baker framework to do it. Baker framework use the engine of the mobile safari. I created the hover and it works in chrome, firefox, opera but not in ipad preview. Do you have any idea what is wrong? Here is my code:

```
.slidebutton {
    position:absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0%;
    background-color: white;
    left:974px;
    transition: width 2s;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari */
    clear:both;
    }
.slidebutton:hover {

    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0%;
    background-color: white;
    left:874px;
    clear:both;
    display: inline;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue on a site recently:

```
//jQuery code
$(".slidebutton").hover(function(){ // this block is strickly to enable our hover effect on mobile ios
    $(this).addClass('active');
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Then you should simply add **.slidebutton.active** to your css:

```
.slidebutton:hover, .slidebutton.active {
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tested that with Safari and it is working (using a Mac).

Using Safari on iPhone not... you have to use Javascript; try this:

```
$('.slidebutton').mouseover(function(event) {
    //apply the css property
}).mouseout(function(event) {
    //apply the css property (reverse)
});
```

Comment: In this case I used jQuery so you should include also jQuery on your project!

Answer (score 0):

I used this to get around this:

```
$(document).delegate(this.classWithHoverState,eventHover,function(e){
            if(e.type=='mouseenter' || e.type=='touchstart'){
                $(this).addClass('hover');
            }else{
                $(this).removeClass('hover');
            }
        })
```

And then just add a .hover class

Answer (score 0):

According to [webonomic](https://dev.webonomic.nl/fixing-the-iphone-css-hover-problem-on-ios), there's a simple but weird solution: Add the `ontouchmove`/`ontouchstart`/`ontouchend` (as a boolean) attribute onto `<html>` or `<body>`.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
……
<body ontouchmove>
    ……
</body>
</html>
```

Note: The original post also suggests `onclick` and `tabindex='0'`, but it doesn't work on iPhone 6 / iOS 12.5.5. (the author tested on iPhone 11 in 2019)